# Angular ng-show depending on function

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

maybe its just a basic misunderstanding, but I have a small issue regarding Angular and ng-show.

I've got a simple form with three input fields. I want to show a div with an infotext, but only if all three input fields are set.

My controller (with controllerAs-Syntax, Alias is 'myControllerCtrl') looks like that:

```
var vm = this;

vm.annualConsumption = null;
vm.calorificVal = null;
vm.zNumber = null;
vm.checkIfAllValuesAreSet = checkIfAllValuesAreSet;


function checkIfAllValuesAreSet() {
    return vm.annualConsumption && vm.calorificVal && vm.zNumber;
}
```

So I put an

```
ng-show="myControllerCtrl.checkIfAllValuesAreSet()"
```

in my div. But it won't show the div if I set all input fields! If I put the condition from the function directly into the ng-show like

```
ng-show="vm.annualConsumption && vm.calorificVal && vm.zNumber"
```

it works. So my question is: Why can't I use the function as an expression for ng-show?

Comment: Try `ng-show="checkIfAllValuesAreSet()"` as controller is already having scope and attach this function to `$scope`

Comment: try just ng-show="checkIfAllValuesAreSet()"

Comment: it will work if you correct it to ng-show="vm.checkIfAllValuesAreSet()" your alias is 'vm' not 'myControllerCtrl' thats why second condition working...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use controllerAs-Syntax. Its alias is "myControllerCtrl".

Comment: if your controller as uses myControllerCtrl as alias, then, your vm.* tests don't will work... something is wrong here. If the problem remains, you could create a jsbin or plunker to show the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-show="myControllerCtrl.checkIfAllValuesAreSet()"` will only get run once when the controller/template loads. So if you change anything on your form, there is nothing to trigger the function again.

you could simply change your ng-show to be:

```
ng-show="vm.annualConsumption && vm.calorificVal && vm.zNumber"
```

which will update immediately if any of these change.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured out myself and told you in my question, I was just curious about why it won't work with the function. But I guess the problem is just as you said, the function will only get called one, not like the binding with the three values direclty... thanks! I think thats the only correct answer to my issue until now.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `$scope`. Attach the function to the scope of the controller, and you are good to go:

```
$scope.checkIfAllValuesAreSet = function() {
   return vm.annualConsumption && vm.calorificVal && vm.zNumber;
}
```

so in your HTML you'll able to do:

```
ng-show="checkIfAllValuesAreSet()"
```

remember, `$scope` are a very important concept of angularjs. Trying to avoid using it it's a **bad** idea.
You can read the docs about $scope [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: Sorry, but at that point i have to disagree... It is NOT a good practice to use the global $scope but instead you should use an own scope like i do, with "var vm = this;" Every AngularJS developer is telling you this.. Otherwise you'll get a lot of scope- errors...

Comment: The $scope it's linked to your actual controller. We are talking about $scope, the "global $scope" you are talking about it's probably $rootScope. And yes, using $rootScope (for those needings) it's a bad practise.

Comment: Just to clarify: when you declare a controller, you can inject its actual scope. using that scope it's perfectly fine, because it's confined in the controller. Every controller has a scope.

Comment: I've had many problems with "$scope" before in previous projects, especially when using ng-repeat and trying to access elements on that scope.. If you don't use something like vm = this, it is difficult, almost impossible, or you loose binding. But thats not the issue here, thanks though!

Take a look at: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030

Comment: No problem, just different opinions, i suppose.You are welcome

Comment: Why don't I need $scope before the function in the ng-show?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function as an expression, but make sure that the function returns a `boolean`.
Try this :

```
function checkIfAllValuesAreSet() {
if( vm.annualConsumption !=null && vm.calorificVal !=null && vm.zNumber !=null){
return true;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary. Take a look at: https://api.jquery.com/Types/ (it isn't about jquery, it's about javascript)

Comment: Will take a look at it. Thanks :)